# How to run a for loop to print individual elements within a string

Tags: python, for-loop

The title is pretty self explanatory. The output only prints out the first letter of the string. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
 string = "hello"

 def string_loop(string):
     for x in string:
         return(x)

 print(string_loop(string))

 output: h
```

Comment: You `return` the very 1st item: `return(x)`; either `print(x)` or turn into `yield` (it seems you use Python)

Comment: Please don't forget to add a language tags in future questions.

Comment: As for your problem, please try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on the code. And think about what the `return` statement really does.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Currently, your method is taking in a value `string` and iterating through it, however as it iterates over the first element, it will return it therefore ending the method call.

```
def string_loop(string):
     for x in string:
         return(x)
```

When you iterate through a string, unlike other collections (lists, dictionaries, ...)  python unpacks it into an array of characters so the first element of the array is the first character which is why you only return "h".

**Solution:**
1) If you wanted to print each character of your string, you have two options:

a)  Simply print inside your method with no return value.

```
def string_loop(string):
     for character in string:
         print(character)
string_loop("hello")
```

b) Add your characters to a list and print out the list returned by the method.

```
def string_loop(string):
     my_list = list()
     for character in string:
         list.append(character)
print(string_loop("hello"))
```

2) On the other hand, if you were trying to print out every string while iterating through a list of strings, you would could iterate through the individual strings in the list

```
def string_loop(string_list):
         for string in string_list:
             print(string)
print(string_loop(["hello","world"]))
```